optimizing `GROUP BY + HAVING max` in postgres
so for the database i'm working with, i'm trying to optimize the following:
SELECT
  MAX(id),
  claim_id
FROM
  tasks
WHERE
  type = 'UNRECONCILIED'
GROUP BY
  claim_id
HAVING
  max(status) IN ('IN_PROGRESS', 'BACKLOG')

i have tried setting up various indices, most obvious of them all being the one on tasks(type, claim_id, status desc, id desc). based on my understanding of how indices work (which i suspect may not be quite right), this index should allow the database to index into each resulting row with no sequential scanning. however, contrary to my reasoning, removing the HAVING clause actually results in a query plan that is cheaper.
my questions are three-fold:

is the above reasoning around HAVING clause incorrect?
is this query more or less as optimized as it can be without resorting to something more drastic? (i.e. caching, removing columns, etc)
if not, what can i do to optimize this further?

(this is for postgres server 14.12, but it seems it's the same for postgres 17 as well)
UPDATE:
the following seems to reproduce the issue.
CREATE TABLE tasks (id INT, status TEXT, type TEXT, claim_id INT);  
INSERT INTO tasks SELECT n, 'DEFAULT', 'DEFAULT', n%10000 FROM generate_series(1, 5000000) n;
INSERT INTO tasks SELECT n, 'DEFAULT', 'UNRECONCILIED', n%10000 FROM generate_series(1, 492000) n;
INSERT INTO tasks SELECT n, 'IN_PROGRESS', 'DEFAULT', n%10000 FROM generate_series(1, 2080000) n;
INSERT INTO tasks SELECT n, 'IN_PROGRESS', 'UNRECONCILIED', n%10000 FROM generate_series(1, 60000) n;
INSERT INTO tasks SELECT n, 'BACKLOG', 'DEFAULT', n%10000 FROM generate_series(1, 373000) n;
INSERT INTO tasks SELECT n, 'BACKLOG', 'UNRECONCILIED', n%10000 FROM generate_series(1, 145000) n;

CREATE index ON tasks (type, claim_id, status DESC, id DESC);
analyze tasks;

EXPLAIN(ANALYZE,BUFFERS,VERBOSE) SELECT
  MAX(id),
  claim_id
FROM
  tasks
WHERE
  type = 'UNRECONCILIED'
GROUP BY
  claim_id
HAVING
  max(status) IN ('IN_PROGRESS', 'BACKLOG');

ANALYZE tasks;
EXPLAIN(ANALYZE,BUFFERS,VERBOSE) SELECT
  MAX(id),
  claim_id
FROM
  tasks
WHERE
  type = 'UNRECONCILIED'
GROUP BY
  claim_id;

on my machine, this generates the following plans:
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                 |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Finalize HashAggregate  (cost=84997.36..85122.34 rows=100 width=8) (actual time=140.889..142.037 rows=10000 loops=1)                                                       |
|   Output: max(id), claim_id                                                                                                                                                |
|   Group Key: tasks.claim_id                                                                                                                                                |
|   Filter: (max(tasks.status) = ANY ('{IN_PROGRESS,BACKLOG}'::text[]))                                                                                                      |
|   Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1681kB                                                                                                                                         |
|   Buffers: shared hit=1568 read=7885 written=5025                                                                                                                          |
|   ->  Gather  (cost=82747.81..84847.39 rows=19996 width=40) (actual time=134.504..137.085 rows=30000 loops=1)                                                              |
|         Output: claim_id, (PARTIAL max(id)), (PARTIAL max(status))                                                                                                         |
|         Workers Planned: 2                                                                                                                                                 |
|         Workers Launched: 2                                                                                                                                                |
|         Buffers: shared hit=1568 read=7885 written=5025                                                                                                                    |
|         ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=81747.81..81847.79 rows=9998 width=40) (actual time=130.276..131.126 rows=10000 loops=3)                                          |
|               Output: claim_id, PARTIAL max(id), PARTIAL max(status)                                                                                                       |
|               Group Key: tasks.claim_id                                                                                                                                    |
|               Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1681kB                                                                                                                             |
|               Buffers: shared hit=1568 read=7885 written=5025                                                                                                              |
|               Worker 0:  actual time=128.426..129.275 rows=10000 loops=1                                                                                                   |
|                 Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1681kB                                                                                                                           |
|                 Buffers: shared hit=488 read=1135 written=638                                                                                                              |
|               Worker 1:  actual time=128.207..128.971 rows=10000 loops=1                                                                                                   |
|                 Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1681kB                                                                                                                           |
|                 Buffers: shared hit=485 read=1140 written=641                                                                                                              |
|               ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on public.tasks  (cost=21031.14..79491.93 rows=300784 width=17) (actual time=68.930..98.723 rows=232333 loops=3)               |
|                     Output: id, status, type, claim_id                                                                                                                     |
|                     Recheck Cond: (tasks.type = 'UNRECONCILIED'::text)                                                                                                     |
|                     Heap Blocks: exact=1938                                                                                                                                |
|                     Buffers: shared hit=1568 read=7885 written=5025                                                                                                        |
|                     Worker 0:  actual time=67.152..98.487 rows=218204 loops=1                                                                                              |
|                       Buffers: shared hit=488 read=1135 written=638                                                                                                        |
|                     Worker 1:  actual time=66.899..98.006 rows=218525 loops=1                                                                                              |
|                       Buffers: shared hit=485 read=1140 written=641                                                                                                        |
|                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tasks_type_claim_id_status_id_idx  (cost=0.00..20850.66 rows=721881 width=0) (actual time=72.248..72.249 rows=697000 loops=1) |
|                           Index Cond: (tasks.type = 'UNRECONCILIED'::text)                                                                                                 |
|                           Buffers: shared read=4267 written=2927                                                                                                           |
| Planning:                                                                                                                                                                  |
|   Buffers: shared hit=40 read=5                                                                                                                                            |
| Planning Time: 0.987 ms                                                                                                                                                    |
| Execution Time: 142.387 ms                                                                                                                                                 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
EXPLAIN 38
ANALYZE
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                 |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Finalize HashAggregate  (cost=82401.13..82501.01 rows=9988 width=8) (actual time=66.175..67.048 rows=10000 loops=1)                                                        |
|   Output: max(id), claim_id                                                                                                                                                |
|   Group Key: tasks.claim_id                                                                                                                                                |
|   Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1169kB                                                                                                                                         |
|   Buffers: shared hit=9453                                                                                                                                                 |
|   ->  Gather  (cost=80203.77..82301.25 rows=19976 width=8) (actual time=61.168..63.368 rows=30000 loops=1)                                                                 |
|         Output: claim_id, (PARTIAL max(id))                                                                                                                                |
|         Workers Planned: 2                                                                                                                                                 |
|         Workers Launched: 2                                                                                                                                                |
|         Buffers: shared hit=9453                                                                                                                                           |
|         ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=79203.77..79303.65 rows=9988 width=8) (actual time=58.242..58.928 rows=10000 loops=3)                                             |
|               Output: claim_id, PARTIAL max(id)                                                                                                                            |
|               Group Key: tasks.claim_id                                                                                                                                    |
|               Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1169kB                                                                                                                             |
|               Buffers: shared hit=9453                                                                                                                                     |
|               Worker 0:  actual time=56.834..57.540 rows=10000 loops=1                                                                                                     |
|                 Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1169kB                                                                                                                           |
|                 Buffers: shared hit=1533                                                                                                                                   |
|               Worker 1:  actual time=56.851..57.513 rows=10000 loops=1                                                                                                     |
|                 Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1169kB                                                                                                                           |
|                 Buffers: shared hit=1527                                                                                                                                   |
|               ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on public.tasks  (cost=19597.82..77802.36 rows=280283 width=8) (actual time=14.225..33.651 rows=232333 loops=3)                |
|                     Output: id, status, type, claim_id                                                                                                                     |
|                     Recheck Cond: (tasks.type = 'UNRECONCILIED'::text)                                                                                                     |
|                     Heap Blocks: exact=2126                                                                                                                                |
|                     Buffers: shared hit=9453                                                                                                                               |
|                     Worker 0:  actual time=12.856..34.759 rows=206025 loops=1                                                                                              |
|                       Buffers: shared hit=1533                                                                                                                             |
|                     Worker 1:  actual time=12.902..34.874 rows=205088 loops=1                                                                                              |
|                       Buffers: shared hit=1527                                                                                                                             |
|                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tasks_type_claim_id_status_id_idx  (cost=0.00..19429.65 rows=672679 width=0) (actual time=16.373..16.373 rows=697000 loops=1) |
|                           Index Cond: (tasks.type = 'UNRECONCILIED'::text)                                                                                                 |
|                           Buffers: shared hit=4267                                                                                                                         |
| Planning:                                                                                                                                                                  |
|   Buffers: shared hit=22                                                                                                                                                   |
| Planning Time: 0.099 ms                                                                                                                                                    |
| Execution Time: 67.340 ms                                                                                                                                                  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
EXPLAIN 37
~



which show a higher cost for the query that filters out some rows via HAVING clause.

Please update the post with the table DDL, including indexes, and the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE,BUFFERS,VERBOSE). Data statistics would also be useful; e.g., total row count and distribution statistics for claim_id, status, and type. With this additional context, it should be possible to create an environment adequate for evaluating different optimization approaches without having the actual data.

MAX(some_text) can result in some unexpected results and is highly dependent on the content. Are you 100% sure this is what you want?

let me work on creating some mock data that's representative. re: MAX(some_text), what i eventually want it to be is the first element in some custom ordering over the enum type on status. here i used MAX(some_text) thinking it would be a simpler starting point than custom-ordered enum.

Please explain what you mean by custom ordering over the enum. By default a Postgres Enum is ordered by the position of the value within the  definition of the Enum; additionally the Min and Max values are also defined by there defined positions. See play with enum sample.

by custom ordering, i meant something like https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/274389/141005

@JohnH sorry for the delay; finally got around to updating the post with some mock data that seem to reproduce the issue.

Please update the post with the results of EXPLAIN(ANALYZE,BUFFERS,VERBOSE): EXPLAIN without those options doesn't provide enough information.

made the updates @JohnH

What are you trying to optimize? The execution times for the queries are reasonable. The query with HAVING is more expensive, and takes longer, because additional work has to be done over the entire set of candidate rows.

in the actual data, the rows are wider so it ends up taking tangibly longer. i'm mainly trying to understand why HAVING would make it slower since i believe the index should allow the query executor to skip over the rows not satisfying the HAVING clause condition.

more specifically, the filtering for HAVING seems to be happening after the group by has been done, but my understanding is that if the index is built on (type, claim_id, id, status) the filtering should theoretically be possible at the time we use the index. i'm not sure if this is due to my incorrect understanding or a limitation on postgres' part.
